# bind class with function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to bind a class in vue JS which depends on a function.

I have :

```
:class="{{this.isMobile() ? 'mobile-chip-overflow' : 'chip-overflow'}}"
```

I have a console error isMobile of null

Comment: from where you getting isMobile could please post all the component code or give a complete example

Comment: isMobile function is import from a abstract js file who contain all the reusable function of the app

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `{{ }}` and `this.` when binding this way, just do this:

```
:class="isMobile() ? 'mobile-chip-overflow' : 'chip-overflow'"
```

and it will work.

**EDIT:**

When using a `.js` file with resusable `functions` please consider to use a `mixin`. However, if you still do not want to use it, you can import the `function` like this:

```
  methods: {
    isMobile: import isMobile from './abstract.js',
  }
```

or even like this:

```
import abstractFunctions from './abstract.js';

export default {
  methods: {
    isMobile: abstractFunctions.isMobile,
  },
};
```

Depending of how are you `exporting` the functions inside `abstract.js`.

Comment: I need 'this' because the function is not in this component , and I have the same error with this code

Comment: Where's exactly the `isMobile()` function? If you need to use the same function in several components then consider to use a `mixin`

Comment: in a file call abstract.js who contain all reusable functions

Comment: And how are you importing this function? Can you show us the code? And as I said above it's important to note that reusable functions used in several components should be inside a `mixin`.

Comment: I import it with extends: abstract

Comment: It's weird because if i use ismobile function in a v-if it works , but for bind class no.

Answer (score 0):

You can make

```
:class="chipClasses"


computed: {
    chipClasses: () {
        return {
            mobile-chip-overflow: this.isMobile(),
            chip-overflow: !this.isMobile()
        }

    }
}
```

Or

```
:class="{mobile-chip-overflow: this.isMobile(),
         chip-overflow: !this.isMobile()
         }"
```

I've done in this second way, and it works.

Comment: No sorry , same problem than above